# My wordpress website occurred into a fatal error how can I solve it?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have this error:

```
Warning: require(/home/gptradin/public_html/wp-content/themes/ecommerce-plusincludes/custom-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gptradin/public_html/wp-content/themes/techno/functions.php on line 78

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/gptradin/public_html/wp-content/themes/ecommerce-plusincludes/custom-header.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/gptradin/public_html/wp-content/themes/techno/functions.php on line 78
```

I can't see my website, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

On line 78 of the file functions.php in your Wordpress installation, there's code which specifies the file custom-header.php as **required**. However, when wordpress looks for that file in the following directory: `/home/gptradin/public_html/wp-content/themes/ecommerce-plusincludes/`, it simply cannot find it.

You need to find where the file custom-header.php is located in your server, and then adjust the code on line 78 in the functions.php file to match that directory.